# How can i customize/design a table in jspdf without autotable?

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

I need to design a table using jsPdf. But it's always showing a default layout. How can I modify the table and make it look the way I want?

I've tried autotable, but somehow it's not running. An API error is showing on console. So I'm thinking of ways to do it without autotable.